# finding the tangent of an angle given the value of the other two tangent of an angle of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given a triangle $ABC$. It is given that the value of $\tan A = \frac13$ and the value of $\tan B=\frac12$. Find the value of $\tan C$.

Comment: What did you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: i use $\frac {y}{x}$ as the tangent and proceed to substitution but i can't get the answer because it always equated to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A+B+C=180^o$

$\tan (A+B+C) = $$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C\over 1-\tan A\tan B - \tan B\tan C - \tan C\tan A$

$\tan(180^o) = 0$

Substitute and get it.

Comment: @aravhinz I thought you already got the answer since you accepted the above answer. Anyway, you get $5\over 6$+$\tan C$ = $1\over 6$$\tan C$  since the numerator has to be zero.

Comment: sorry i thought i can get it.

Comment: @aravhinz So, $\tan C = -1$ , $C = 135^o$ is my answer.

Comment: is my final equation $0=\frac{\frac56+\frac56tanC}{\frac56-\frac56tanC}$ correct. if it is correct how can this arrived to your equation $\frac56+tanC=\frac16tanC$?

Comment: @aravhinz You are absolutely right. Now, numerator is zero. so, tan C = -1.

Comment: it will become $\frac56+\frac56tanC=0$

Comment: @aravhinz You are right.

Comment: is it ok to disregard the denominator?

Comment: @aravhinz denominator doesn't matter since numerator is 0. Anything divided by 0 is 0.

Comment: yes got it... thank you. @winvineeth

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Given triangle $\rm{ABC}$, $A+B+C=\pi$. You can also use trigonometric identity
$$
\tan (x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}.
$$